# calculating time between other time spaces Update

Tags: javascript, html

**Desc:** In the html table I have:

- **2 columns with data to enter:** ( sample values ​​are inserted in the example, you must enter it yourself for the script to work )

  a) start,  // the user enters this field

  b) end. (info: end must be larger than start for it to work properly) // the user enters this field
- **4 columns with data that are calculated / are constant: (now it is working)**

  a) actual (end-start),

  b) normative (const, in example 8:00, in practice differently)

  c) overtime ( = |normative - actual | (>=0) )  // if actual(>)normative

  d) tobeworkout ( = |normative - actual | (=<0) ) // if actual(<)normative
- **2 columns with data that I am trying to calculate:**  (what I trying to achieve)

  a) overtime_days, ( if actual>normative then: if start and end (work time) is between 6:00(>=) and 22:00(=<) then: overtime_days = actual-normative )

  b) overtime_night ( if actual>normative then: if start and end (work time) is between 0:00 to 6:00(<) and 22:00(>) to 23:59 then: overtime_days = actual-normative )

  *notes:*

  it is necessary to consider the case when e.g. it starts at 5:00 and ends at 20:00, then night and overtime and daytime overtime are counted: normative = 8:00, from 5:00 to 6:00 = 1:00 overtime_night, and 6:00 to 14:00 normative, 14:00 to 20:00 overtime_days

**What I did?**

- I don't know how to catch time between start and end, I'm looking for ideas
  , because it's a hard topic for me

**Code:** (the code does not include calculations for the searched values)

```js
    document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        const classList = e.target.classList;
        if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
            const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
            const [start, end, actual] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual')];
            const value = diff(start.value, end.value);
            actual.value = value;
            

        }
    });

    document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        const classList = e.target.classList;
        if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
            const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
            const [actual, normative, overtime, tobeworkout] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.actual,.normative,.overtime,.tobeworkout')];
            if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) >= 0) {
                overtime.value = diff(normative.value, actual.value);
                tobeworkout.value = "00:00";
            }
            if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) <= 0) {
                tobeworkout.value = diff(actual.value, normative.value);
                overtime.value = "00:00";
            }
        }
    });

// this function calculate a difference for a logical purposes
    function diffMs(start, end) { 
        return +start.split(":").join('') - +end.split(":").join('');
    }



    function msToTime(duration) {
        const minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
            hours = Math.floor(duration / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        return twoOrMoreDigits(hours) + ":" + twoOrMoreDigits(minutes);
    }

    function twoOrMoreDigits(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    function timeToMs(time) {
        if (time) { // may be "" if the value is not set
            const [hours, minutes] = time.split(":").map(str => parseInt(str, 10));
            return (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60 * 1000;
        }
        return 0;
    }

  

    function diff(start, end) {
        return msToTime(timeToMs(end) - timeToMs(start));
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>start</th>
      <th>end</th>
      <th>actual</th>
      <th>normative</th>
      <th>overtime</th>
      <th>tobeworkout</th>
      <th>overtime_days</th>
      <th>overtime_night</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime" id="overtime_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="tobeworkout" id="tobeworkout_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime_days" id="overtime_days_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime_night" id="overtime_night_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime" id="overtime_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="tobeworkout" id="tobeworkout_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime_days" id="overtime_days_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="overtime_night" id="overtime_night_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notes:

Please do not change the code I have already written.

The code is in partialView, partialView refreshes after changing options on dropdownbox (selectbox).

I use asp.net /net core 3.0

**Changes: !!!!**

- This has changed:  (make night are always night)
- if it has normative = 08: 00 and actual = 08: 00,

  - but he worked from 04:00 to 12:00 (at night from 04:00 to 6:00)

    - he should count 02:00 hours as night hours (
      at night from 22:00 to 6:00)
  - as if he worked from 15:00 to 23:00 (at night from 22:00 to 23:00)

    - this should count 'overtime_night' / 'additional_nigth' as ​​01:00  (
      at night from 22:00 to 6:00)

Comment: So when start/end = 02:00 - 10:00, then `overtime_night` is still to be zero, right? (because total is not more than normative)

Comment: @trincot  yes, in that case, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the rules, this should do it:

```js
(function () { // create a closure to avoid name conficts
    const table = document.querySelector('table');
    const minStart =  6*60; // 06:00
    const maxEnd   = 22*60; // 22:00

    class TimeInput {
        constructor(input) {
            this.input = input;
            this.minutes = input.value.split(":").reduce((minutes, seconds) => minutes*60+ +seconds);
        }
        set value(minutes) {
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.input.value = [Math.floor(minutes / 60), minutes % 60].map(i => ("0"+i).slice(-2)).join(":");
        }
        valueOf() {
            return this.minutes;
        }
    }

    function updateRow(row) {
        let inputs = {}
        for (let input of row.querySelectorAll("input")) inputs[input.className] = new TimeInput(input);
        let {start, end, actual, normative, overtime, tobeworkout, overtime_days, overtime_night} = inputs;
        if (!start) return; // Not a data row
        actual.value = end - start; // NB: calls valueOf methods
        let diff = actual - normative;
        overtime.value = Math.max(0, diff);
        tobeworkout.value = Math.max(0, -diff);
        let workedEarly = Math.max(0, minStart - start);
        let workedLate = Math.max(0, end - maxEnd);    
        overtime_night.value = Math.min(overtime, workedEarly + workedLate);
        overtime_days.value = overtime - overtime_night;    
    }

    table.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        updateRow(e.target.closest("TR"));
    });

    for (let row of table.rows) updateRow(row);
})(); // execute immediately
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>start</th>
      <th>end</th>
      <th>actual</th>
      <th>normative</th>
      <th>overtime</th>
      <th>tobeworkout</th>
      <th>overtime_days</th>
      <th>overtime_night</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="actual" id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime" id="overtime_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="tobeworkout" id="tobeworkout_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime_days" id="overtime_days_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime_night" id="overtime_night_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime" id="overtime_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="tobeworkout" id="tobeworkout_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime_days" id="overtime_days_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input size ="5" class="overtime_night" id="overtime_night_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have introduced a class which deals with the conversion between minutes and hh:mm notation. That way the rest of the code can concentrate only on the logic, based on minutes.

NB: For the last 6 columns, I would not use `type="time"`, as strictly speaking these are not times of the day, but *durations*. If the browser's locale uses AM/PM notation, then the browser may display AM/PM in those values too, which makes no sense when thinking of durations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207668/discussion-on-answer-by-trincot-calculating-time-between-other-time-spaces-updat).